# Flutter How to listen to sensor data and record when values reached?

Tags: flutter, stream

I would like to listen to accelerometer data and record instances only when they hit certain values. I'm unsure of the best way to write this and think it should be something of the form

```dart
  _updateSensorData() {
    userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
        if(event.x != null){
          _accelerometer = Accelerometer(event.x, event.y, event.z);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  bool _extremeSensor() {
    if(_accelerometer != null){
      return (_accelerometer .xAcceleration).abs() > 0.5;
    }
    return false;
  }

  _startRecording() {
    while (true) {
      _updateSensorData();
      if (_extremeSensor()) {
        _rideTimer = Timer.periodic(
            Duration(milliseconds: Constants.normaliseTimerCycleInMilliseconds), (timer) async {
              //save it
              _updateSensorData();
            });
        _rideTimer.cancel();
      }
    }
  }
```

In my head this should keep grabbing data as fast as possible, then if it matches the condition in _extremeSensor() it should start a timer and record stuff, until the condition fails.

This feels like a hacky way to do it, the while loop. Ideally I just want a stream to happen and I listen in, then react accordingly. The problem is the listen event seems to fire only once so I must keep doing it.

This code quickly kills my system. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it might be:

```dart
  _startRecording() {
    _rideTimer = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(milliseconds: Constants.normaliseTimerCycleInMilliseconds),
        (timer) async {
      _updateSensorData();
      if (_extremeSensor()) {
        //save it
      }
    });
  }
```